# Cmake - fatal error U1073: don't know how to make a specific library

Tags: c++, cmake

I am trying to build my project under Windows. On Linux it has no issues.

Here is my main `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)
project(Vibranium_Core)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(FLATBUFFERS_MAX_PARSING_DEPTH 16)
set(FLATBUFFERS_LOCATION "E:/vcpkg/packages/flatbuffers_x86-windows")
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS ON)

if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID MATCHES "GNU|Clang")
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -O0")
endif()

if(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")
    execute_process(
            COMMAND git rev-list --count HEAD
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_VERSION
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    execute_process(
            COMMAND git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_BRANCH
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )

    execute_process(
            COMMAND git log -1 --format=%h
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_COMMIT_HASH
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
    execute_process(
            COMMAND git --no-pager log -1 --format=%ai
            WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}
            OUTPUT_VARIABLE GIT_RELEASED_ON
            OUTPUT_STRIP_TRAILING_WHITESPACE
    )
else(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")
    set(GIT_BRANCH "")
    set(GIT_COMMIT_HASH "")
endif(EXISTS "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/.git")

message(STATUS "VibraniumCore current branch: ${GIT_BRANCH}")
message(STATUS "VibraniumCore Version: ${GIT_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "VibraniumCore commit hash: ${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}")
message(STATUS "Released on: ${GIT_RELEASED_ON}")

message(STATUS "Generating version.h")

configure_file(
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/version.h.in
        ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Common/Version.h
)


find_package(Boost 1.72.0 COMPONENTS date_time serialization regex)
find_package(Threads)

add_definitions(-DGIT_COMMIT_HASH="${GIT_COMMIT_HASH}")
add_definitions(-DGIT_BRANCH="${GIT_BRANCH}")
add_definitions(-DGIT_VERSION="${GIT_VERSION}")
add_definitions(-DGIT_RELEASED_ON="${GIT_RELEASED_ON}")

include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR})

if("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" EQUAL "8")
    message(STATUS "Target is 64 bits")
    if (WIN32)
        set(WINXXBITS Win64)
    endif(WIN32)
else("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" EQUAL "8")
    message(STATUS "Target is 32 bits")
    if (WIN32)
        set(WINXXBITS Win32)
    endif(WIN32)
endif("${CMAKE_SIZEOF_VOID_P}" EQUAL "8")

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH ${CMAKE_MODULE_PATH} "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/")
find_package(MySQL REQUIRED)
if(WIN32)
    find_package(Flatbuffers REQUIRED
            PATHS ${FLATBUFFERS_LOCATION})
    else()
    find_package(Flatbuffers REQUIRED
        PATHS /usr/local/flatbuffers)
endif()
include_directories(${MYSQL_INCLUDE_DIR})

add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Common)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Core/WorldServer)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Core/AuthServer)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/ClientEmulator)
add_subdirectory(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Source/Game)
add_subdirectory(Tests)


set_target_properties(VibraniumCoreTests PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
set_target_properties(gtest PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
set_target_properties(gmock PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
set_target_properties(gtest_main PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)
set_target_properties(gmock_main PROPERTIES EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL TRUE)

set_target_properties(
        Common WorldServer AuthServer ClientEmulator Game
        PROPERTIES
        ARCHIVE_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib"
        LIBRARY_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/lib"
        RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin"
)
```

Here is `AuthServer` CMakeLists.txt:

```
add_executable(AuthServer
        AuthServer.cpp
        ${PRIVATE_SOURCES}
        ../Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase.cpp
        ../Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase.h
        ../Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase/Accounts.h
        ../Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase/AccountRoles.h
        ../Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase/Accounts.cpp
        ../Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase/AccountRoles.cpp
        ../Memory/LoginMemory.h
        ../Memory/LoginMemory.cpp
        AuthServer.h
        Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp Server/AuthServerOpcodes.h)
target_include_directories(AuthServer PUBLIC ../Database ../Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase/ ../../Game)
target_link_libraries(AuthServer PUBLIC Common Game ${Boost_LIBRARIES})

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
    message(STATUS "Configs folder will be created: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs")
    file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/)
endif()

if(NOT EXISTS ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/AuthServer.conf)
message(STATUS "New AuthServer Config file in will be installed in: ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs")
add_custom_command(
        TARGET AuthServer POST_BUILD
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/AuthServer.conf.dist
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/bin/configs/AuthServer.conf)
endif()
```

Here is my Game library `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
add_library(
        Game
        SHARED
        Accounts/AccountManager.cpp Accounts/AccountManager.h)

target_include_directories(Game PUBLIC /usr/local/mysql/connector-c++-/include)
target_include_directories(Game PUBLIC . ${MYSQL_LIBRARY})
target_include_directories(Game PUBLIC ../Core/AuthServer)
target_include_directories(Game PUBLIC ../Core/WorldServer)
target_link_libraries(Game PUBLIC ${MYSQL_CONNECTOR_LIBRARY} ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} Common)
```

When I try to build I get this output and error:

```
====================[ Build | AuthServer | Debug ]==============================
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2020.1.3\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build E:\Vibranium-Core\cmake-build-debug --target AuthServer
Scanning dependencies of target Common
[  4%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Config.cpp.obj
Config.cpp
[  8%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Logger.cpp.obj
Logger.cpp
[ 13%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Database/MySQLConnection.cpp.obj
MySQLConnection.cpp
[ 17%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Database/MySQLTable.cpp.obj
MySQLTable.cpp
[ 21%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Banner.cpp.obj
Banner.cpp
[ 26%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Database/MySQLTableBase.cpp.obj
MySQLTableBase.cpp
[ 30%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Memory/Memory.cpp.obj
Memory.cpp
[ 34%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Server/Server.cpp.obj
Server.cpp
Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
- add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to the compiler command line; or
- add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target).
[ 39%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Server/Client.cpp.obj
Client.cpp
Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
- add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to the compiler command line; or
- add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target).
[ 43%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Server/Packet.cpp.obj
Packet.cpp
Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
- add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to the compiler command line; or
- add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target).
[ 47%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Server/Protocol/Opcodes.cpp.obj
Opcodes.cpp
[ 52%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Server/WorldSession.cpp.obj
WorldSession.cpp
[ 56%] Building CXX object Source/Common/CMakeFiles/Common.dir/Server/AuthSession.cpp.obj
AuthSession.cpp
[ 60%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\Common.dll
   Creating library ..\..\bin\lib\Common.lib and object ..\..\bin\lib\Common.exp
   Creating library ..\..\bin\lib\Common.lib and object ..\..\bin\lib\Common.exp
[ 60%] Built target Common
Scanning dependencies of target Game
[ 65%] Building CXX object Source/Game/CMakeFiles/Game.dir/Accounts/AccountManager.cpp.obj
AccountManager.cpp
Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
- add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to the compiler command line; or
- add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target).
[ 69%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\bin\Game.dll
[ 69%] Built target Game
Scanning dependencies of target AuthServer
[ 73%] Building CXX object Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/AuthServer.cpp.obj
AuthServer.cpp
Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately. For example:
- add -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to the compiler command line; or
- add _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 to your project's Preprocessor Definitions.
Assuming _WIN32_WINNT=0x0601 (i.e. Windows 7 target).
[ 78%] Building CXX object Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/__/Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase.cpp.obj
LoginDatabase.cpp
[ 82%] Building CXX object Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/__/Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase/Accounts.cpp.obj
Accounts.cpp
[ 86%] Building CXX object Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/__/Database/Implementation/LoginDatabase/AccountRoles.cpp.obj
AccountRoles.cpp
[ 91%] Building CXX object Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/__/Memory/LoginMemory.cpp.obj
LoginMemory.cpp
[ 95%] Building CXX object Source/Core/AuthServer/CMakeFiles/AuthServer.dir/Server/AuthServerOpcodes.cpp.obj
AuthServerOpcodes.cpp
NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'bin\lib\Game.lib'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\bin\HostX64\x64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

I have two questions:

1. Why I see this message `Please define _WIN32_WINNT or _WIN32_WINDOWS appropriately.` and how can I fix it? I see this only on Windows. On Linux it does not apepar.
2. How can I fix the error `NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'bin\lib\Game.lib'` ?

P.S.
Here is what I have in the build dir:

[image]

Comment: Please show the definition of the AuthServer target. Also tell us if there is *any* game.lib in your build directory.

Comment: @Botje i've edited the question with the requested info.

Comment: I think your second problem is caused by the order of your add_subdirectory statements: you should move the Game one before the AuthServer one. Currently CMake has no idea that Game is a target you define yourself, so it assumes there is a Game.lib somewhere

Comment: No change even If I place it above.

Comment: It should work like that. Probably something you're not showing us.

Answer (score 0):

EDITED:

I'm not sure about issue #2 upon second viewing. I'd have to have access to more of your codebase.

But I think I can answer #1.

#1.) This is a message from boost:
[D_WIN32_WINNT compiler warning with Boost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000231/d-win32-winnt-compiler-warning-with-boost)

To fix issue number 1 you should include a specific windows header file.
Add following line in your top source code. As was specified by user Hill in the post I linked.

```
#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

This will define _WIN32_WINNT appropriately.

Ideas to try and fix number #2.

Use a different generator. I don't recommmend Nmake because it is super slow anyway and gives less than stellar error messages. I'd recommend Visual Studio or Ninja.

Comment: How can I fix 1 and 2 ?

Comment: What has issue 2 to do with Boost? Is it related to boost this issue?

Comment: Apologies upon second viewing, I made an edit to my answer.

Comment: I am using Visual studio as a compiler. What do you mean ?

Comment: Visual Studio isn't a compiler it's a generator. The compiler is called MSVC. I'm referring to your error message "NMAKE : fatal error U1073: don't know how to make 'bin\lib\Game.lib'" It seems like you are using Nmake Makefiles. If you aren't I apologize.